# Is the Octogon Mathematical Magazine still accepting paper submissions?

Tags: journals, paper-submission

Is the [Octogon Mathematical Magazine](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matsefi/Octogon_pre/index.php?menu=home) still accepting paper submissions?

The latest contents in the [Archive section](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/~matsefi/Octogon_pre/index.php?menu=archive) is Volume 20. No. 1 April, 2012, though I am not particularly sure if this website is updated (or if this is even the *correct website* that I should be looking at).

I did check [WorldCat](https://www.worldcat.org/title/octogon-mathematical-magazine) and it appears that the journal is still in print.

> Is **Octogon Mathematical Magazine** indeed still in print?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, they are still in print. The issues through 2019 can be found [here](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/%7Ematsefi/Octogon/index.php?menu=archive).

Comment: It looks like the previous issues have been uploaded/updated.  Thanks for your answer, @StanleyRabinowitz

Comment: The [link](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/%7Ematsefi/Octogon/index.php?menu=archive) appears to be broken.  =(

Comment: @ARNIEBEBITA-DRIS The link seems to be working today.

Comment: The archive only goes up to 2019. Is the journal still publishing?

Comment: Yes, Octogon is still publishing, @StanleyRabinowitz.  (I think the archive only shows the table of contents for each volume/number, while authors who submit accepted papers receive a printed copy of the journal via postal mail.)  So there may be a lag time in-between.

Answer (score 2):

**Yes**, the *Octogon Mathematical Magazine* is indeed still in print.

I was advised by the current Editor-in-Chief to send my paper submissions (in LaTeX and PDF formats) via [e-mail](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/%7Ematsefi/Octogon_pre/index.php?menu=contacts).

Here are the [Rules](https://www.uni-miskolc.hu/%7Ematsefi/Octogon_pre/index.php?menu=rules) governing submission to this journal.

(**Edit June 13 2020, in response to [Nate Eldredge](https://academia.stackexchange.com/u/1010)'s questions in the comments:**  Per an e-mail reply from the current Editor-in-Chief:)

> Dear Sir, we reorganized the webpage of Octogon, if we finished you can see the previous issues. Octogon appears two time /year (April and October) printed version. Best regards MB

Comment: So, have they in fact published any other issues since 2012?

Comment: Yes, that appears to be the case, @NateEldredge.

Comment: On some other website, or only on paper, or what?

Comment: Let me ask the current Editor-in-Chief again.

Comment: I sent a clarificatory e-mail to the current Editor-in-Chief, @NateEldredge.  I will get back to you ASAP, and will update my answer accordingly.

Comment: I'm merely curious, but I think it would be worth considering whether you really want to publish in a journal which nobody seems to be able to find, and for which it's hard to tell whether 8 years of issues even exist.

Comment: I have updated my answer, @NateEldredge with a copy of the e-mail reply from the current Editor-in-Chief of the Octogon Mathematical Magazine.